# AngularJS $scope.$on multiple events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I have a scenario when I need to listen to 2 different events transmitted via `$scope.$emit` and I want to act **only when both have happened**.

So for example if the events triggering is the following:

```
$scope.$emit('first');
// do nothing
$scope.$emit('second');
// execute something
$scope.$emit('first');
// Do nothing
$scope.$emit('first');
// Do nothing
$scope.$emit('second');
// execute something
```

Is there anything that does it out of the box? Ideally like

`$scope.$on('first', 'second', function() {});`

I've considered doing the following:

```
var triggeredEvents = [];
$scope.$on('first', function() {
    notifyEventTriggered('first');
});

$scope.$on('second', function() {
    notifyEventTriggered('second');
});
function notifyEventTriggered(event) {
    if (triggeredEvents.indexOf(event) == -1) {
         triggeredEvents.push(event);
    }
    if (triggeredEvents.length > 1) {
        execute();
        triggeredEvents.length = 0;
    }
}
```

So is there something that does it simpler? Or some suggestions on how to improve it? Other than creating a service for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to do it. I would personally attach a new method to $rootScope like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qv6m2drz/5/

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.onAllEvents = (function() {

    var watchedEvents = {};    
    return onAllEvents;

    /*
     * Attach listeners to all events
     */
    function onAllEvents(events, fn){
        if(!events || !events.length) return ;

      events.forEach(function(evt){
        watchedEvents[evt] = false;
        this.$on(evt, function(){
            watchedEvents[evt] = true;
          tryExecute(fn);
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }

    /* 
     * Check if all `watchedEvents` have fired. If yes, run fn() and reset the events
     */
    function tryExecute(fn){
        var shouldExecute = true;
        for(evt in watchedEvents){
        if(watchedEvents.hasOwnProperty(evt) && !watchedEvents[evt]){
            shouldExecute = false;
        }
      }

      if(shouldExecute){        
        fn();
        for(evt in watchedEvents){
          if(watchedEvents.hasOwnProperty(evt)){
            watchedEvents[evt] = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })();
}]);
```